# C# - Compiling finished application / Using a file from inside the application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-construction, compilation

I want my finished and compiled application to be a single executable file. There is a file I need to read from that I want to be inside the app.

So, my two questions:

How do I, in Visual Studio, add a file into the app and read from it?

How do I compile everything into one application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would most likely look at how to use a Resource / ResourceManager

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for I think http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: What about compiling though, how do I get everything into one file?

Comment: Everything you place in the resources is available from your program so just add the file to the resources and then you can access it.

Comment: I'm quite a noob here, I seriously mean how do I compile? As in, I'm in VS with all my code, how do I turn that into a .exe

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of open source executable compressors. NETZ should do the job. It allows you to compress application files and pack them into one executable.

http://madebits.com/netz/

Answer (score 0):

1- RightClick on your project -> Add -> Existing Item

2- Make sure its `Build Action` is `Embedded Resource`

Then you can read your file(*embedded resource*) as (YourNamespace + "." + FileName)

```
Stream s = System.Reflection.Assembly
   .GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.ReadMe.txt");
```

---

PS: this will give you all embedded resources names

```
string[] resources = System.Reflection.Assembly
   .GetExecutingAssembly()
   .GetManifestResourceNames();
```